# How do I figure out what is wrong with my Outlook signatures?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've been trying to edit my signatures in the tools| options dialogue box, but it won't let me edit anything. Does anyone have any idea why it's not working and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using? This will help in providing you with a useful answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's 2003 or 2007

Comment: In Outlook 2013, it is File, Office Account. I'm sure you can figure it out... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870929?SmcNavTabIndex=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a work computer/email account then they may have been disabled by your network admin.

Specifically the "**Do not allow creating, replying, or forwarding signatures for e-mail messages**" Office policy (or similar; how it's worded depends on the version of the Office the policy templates used are for) can be used to prevent editing signatures.

More info:

[Remove existing Outlook signatures using a Group Policy Object](http://support.exclaimer.com/topic/543871-remove-existing-outlook-signatures-using-a-group-policy-object/)

Blurb:

> You have installed Mail Disclaimers but some of your users still have a signature applied directly by Microsoft Outlook. You want to remove their existing Outlook signatures and prevent them from setting up signatures in Microsoft Outlook in future.

If this is what's going on, then you'll need to speak to your work's IT staff about disabling the policy for you.

Comment: I've been assured that this is not the case in my company. Thanks for eliminating some possibilities! :)

Answer (score -1):

To create a new signature, open Outlook and click the "File" tab.

1. Click "Options" in the menu list on the left side of the Account Information screen.
2. On the Outlook Options dialog box, click "Mail" in the list of options on the left side of the dialog box.
3. On the Mail screen, click "Signatures" in the Compose messages section.
4. Click "New" under the Select signature to edit box on the Signatures and Stationery dialog box.
5. A dialog box displays asking for a name for this signature. Enter a descriptive name in the edit box and click "OK".
6. You are returned to the Signatures and Stationery dialog box and the name you entered displays in the Select signature to edit box. If it’s the only signature, it will be automatically selected. Enter the text for your signature in the Edit signature box. Select the text and apply font, size, and other character and paragraph formatting as desired. Click OK to accept your changes and close the dialog box.
7. Click "OK" on the Outlook Options dialog box to close it.
8. Now, when you create a new email message, the default signature is added to the body of your email automatically. If you only have one signature set up, that will be the default signature.

Source with pictures: http://www.howtogeek.com/173548/how-to-create-a-new-signature-in-outlook-2013/

Comment: I have signatures already, I need to edit two of them, but it will not allow me to.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question -- which is about editing signatures **not** creating new ones.